# Opening hdf5 file from pandas.HDFStore - get all keys and root.attributes?

Tags: io, pandas, hdf5, pytables

This seems a bit silly that I can't figure this out, but I'm really at a loss here.

So let's say I have this:

```
In[6]: store
Out[6]: 
<class 'pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore'>
File path: E:\Users\Dan\Desktop\Cell1-Wash-out-001\Cell1-Wash-out-001.h5
/voltage_recording            frame        (shape->[3200000,4])
```

Which is fine, and I can access both store.voltage_recording or store.root.attributes fine.

But once I close the file, I cannot seem to how to reopen it in a way that I can return these values again.

I know with pd.read_hdf() I can return, for example, the voltage_recording key. But I can't figure out how to get the whole pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore object back.

Is there a function somewhere I'm missing? I know I can also open the file itself with pytables, but that doesn't seem to be getting me where I want to go either.

Comment: you just open like normal ``store = pd.HDFStore(filename,mode='r')`` (mode is append by default, but if you aren't modifying doesn't matter). ``to_hdf/read_hdf`` auto open/close.

Comment: ha, that should have been obvious. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

quoted from Jeff in the comments:

> "you just open like normal store = pd.HDFStore(filename,mode='r')
>   (mode is append by default, but if you aren't modifying doesn't
>   matter). to_hdf/read_hdf auto open/close."